# Is there a way to mimick a google/yahoo finance Ajax call?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, yahoo

I am aware if you try to scrape the google/yahoo finance websites you're at risk of being blocked by their server. I was therefore wondering what if you could spoof the google/yahoo ajax call (which they use to update the prices on the webpage if you leave it open) back to the server each time you wanted a price, surely the google/yahoo server wouldnt count this towards the daily request limit?

Is this possible?

Comment: Don't both of those companies offer a data API which allows you to legitimately do just that?

Comment: google don't offer commodities futures, so i looked at yahoo and there's a limit on the number of requests per day.

Comment: There's a reason for that. If you want to have access to all that data at unlimited rates, you need to look into paying for it from one of the financial firms that provide that type of data.

Comment: So you're asking how to circumvent Google's and Yahoo's security? Don't think they're stupid. They *will* log your IP and track your requests.

Comment: It's hardly security is it? Google/yahoo make an ajax call from my computer to request data, i also want to do it......?? How can it be ok for me to leave the browser open and the graph update, but i cant build an application which does the same :s

Comment: @jvenema, as far as i'm aware 15-min delayed data (which yahoo and google provide) is close-to-free

Comment: @James it is the same as going to a bookstore and reading an entire book instead of browsing and purchasing it.  It's not a public funded library, abuse of a service will just make it worse for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to do it via JavaScript, you'll probably run into problems with the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). You can't do ajax requests to Google/Yahoo from one of your own sites (when not using an official JavaScript API provided by Google/Yahoo).
You can try it using another programming language by inspecting the http calls using [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or similar, and rebuilding the request with the correct headers. This will probably violate the terms of service though (getting you banned), and might even be illegal.